# Object reference error when binding table info along with dropdown in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, datatable, dropdown

I have a table where I am trying to assign some values to every row on button click update.

my view is as follows

```
@model handbook.ViewModel.HREmployeeRelationVM

@{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "AssignToHr", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div class="table-reponsive box">
            <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Employee Name</th>
                        <th>Location</th>
                        <th>Department</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.EmployeeList.Count(); i++)
                   {
                       <tr>
                            <td>@Model.EmployeeList[i].CanditateId</td>
                            <td>@Model.EmployeeList[i].CanditateName</td>
                            <td>@Model.EmployeeList[i].CanditateEmail</td>
                            <td>@Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId[" + i + "]", new SelectList(Model.EmployeeList[i].UserList, "Value", "Text"))</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br />
        </div>
    }
</body>
```

My controller is as follows

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            HREmployeeRelationVM her = new HREmployeeRelationVM();
            her.EmployeeList = new List<HREmpRelation>();
            List<SelectListItem> usermaster = new List<SelectListItem>();
            var users = _context.Usermasters;
            usermaster.Add(new SelectListItem
           {
                Text = "Select HR",
                Value = "0"
            });
            foreach (var usr in users)
            {
                usermaster.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = usr.UserName,
                    Value = Convert.ToString(usr.Id)
                });
            }
            var canditatelist = _context.EmployeeBasicInformations;
            foreach (var item in canditatelist)
            {
                her.EmployeeList.Add(new HREmpRelation
                {
                    CanditateName = item.EmployeeFirstName + " " + item.EmployeeLastName,
                    CanditateId = item.EmployeeId,
                    CanditateEmail = item.EmployeeEmail,
                    UserList = usermaster
                });
            }
            return View(her);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(HREmployeeRelationVM hREmployeeRelationVM)
        {
        }
```

my model is as follows

```
public class HREmployeeRelationVM
    {
        public int[] HRID { get; set; }
        public List<HREmpRelation> EmployeeList { get; set; }
    }
    public class HREmpRelation
    {
        public int CanditateId { get; set; }
        public string CanditateName { get; set; }
        public string CanditateEmail { get; set; }
        public string hrid { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> UserList { get; set; }
    }
```

I am able to load the records along with the dropdown values but when I try to update
I am getting 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I am not sure where i am wrong . Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the Submit button, a `POST` request is generated which causes the `Index` method decorated with the `[HttpPost]` attribute to execute. You don't instantiate any parts of your model in that action method, hence you get a `NullReferenceException` when the view is rendered.

Data is not shared across action methods because HTTP is stateless. Each one is invoked in isolation. When a request is made, the controller class is instantiated and the selected method is executed. Once the response has been sent, the controller class is destroyed.